# Updating Incremental Values in a Column for a Related Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, forum

I'm working on fixing our (forum) database as it seems that several posts in certain threads are showing up with the same post number (#2). It seems that they all hold a position of "1" within each respective forum thread.

I've managed to find a query that will set these position values to the proper number via the query below:

```
select @i := -1; update `xf_post` set position = (select @i := @i + 1) where thread_id=1;
```

Unfortunately, I've only been doing this update query through the MySQL command line where I'm constantly selecting the Up Arrow key, incrementing the 'thread_id' value by 1, and hitting the Return key. Is there a faster way to do this through a loop or cursor? I'm not very familiar with the other parts of the SQL syntax and I only get by with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the numbers that you want for each thread:

```
select thread_id,
       (case when @prev = thread_id then @rn := 1 else @rn := @rn + 1 end) as rn,
       @prev = @threadid
from xf_post p cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @thread_id = -1) const
order by thread_id, position
```

You can test this out to be sure that it produces the right values.  Next you can do an `update` with a `join`:

```
update xf_post join
       (select thread_id, post_id,
               (case when @prev = thread_id then @rn := 1 else @rn := @rn + 1 end) as rn,
               @prev = @threadid
        from xf_post p cross join
             (select @rn := 0, @thread_id = -1) const
        order by thread_id, post_id
       ) toupdate
       on xf_post.post_id = toupdate.post_id
    set xf_post.position = toupdate.rn;
```